# Which image format to use in my app?

Tags: android, svg, png, jpeg, wallpaper

In my college project I have created an app that sets animated images(embedded in the app) as the wallpaper.My question is which image format should I have to use for my images whether svg,png or jpeg for stunning looks on any screen resolution for mobile phones.
Please reply
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I will give answer in detail for this because this is important to select which image format to use for developer.I am just sharing my experience.

Given the current necessity to consider HDPI devices, the shortcomings of bitmap graphics are obvious. In case density were limited to only 2 variants – retina and non-retina, it would still be acceptable, and no one would’ve taken the trouble to tackle the vector graphics challenges that come up on the web nowadays. But we’ve got 1.5x, 2x and 3x devices, and collecting movable object blocks for each of them no longer seems like a good idea.

On the one hand, the lossless bitmap has one advantages that in my opinion outweighs all the service shortcomings – it’s stable. You can be sure that the icon will look exactly the way you’ve drawn it. Pixel for pixel. The question is whether this precision is required in each specific case.

**It turns out that the SVG format has got the following advantages:**

- It doesn’t weigh much, so it will load faster.
- Looks good on highDPI displays.
- Totally flexible and scalable.

**The PNG format has the following factor in its favor:**

- Stability.

***My Personal opinion is in android the best format of Image is PNG as it light compare to JPG,JPEG etc.So its easy to draw and take less time to perform the operation while using these images.***

**You can check some links for research more from below:**

1). Best Link to refer is

https://elfsight.com/blog/2017/05/svg-png-jpeg-choose-the-image-format-for-your-website/[enter link description here](https://elfsight.com/blog/2017/05/svg-png-jpeg-choose-the-image-format-for-your-website/)

2).https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/jpg-png-svg-web-beginners-guide/?utm_campaign=blog&utm_content=jpg-png-svg&utm_medium=which-one-is-the-best&utm_source=quor[a](https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/jpg-png-svg-web-beginners-guide/?utm_campaign=blog&utm_content=jpg-png-svg&utm_medium=which-one-is-the-best&utm_source=quora)

3). https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exporting-graphics-for-mobile-apps-png-or-jpeg--mobile-5154[enter link description here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exporting-graphics-for-mobile-apps-png-or-jpeg--mobile-5154)

Comment: performance of svg images is questionable. Load speed depends on more factors than file size

Comment: @egoldx thank x for sharing your experience...

Answer (score 1):

png format make our android app light weight as compared to using full hd jpeg format.

it's all your choice, but make sure you paste image in drawable(Resource folder).

Answer (score 0):

If your main issue is different sreeen resolutions, you should provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities as specified in android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Images in the drawable resource folder will be scaled if an alternative in not supplied. You can specify different images to use depending on the screen size by creating another drawable resource folder. For example, bitmaps for high-density screens should go in drawable-hdpi/.